# Reading a file from html input tag to a variable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-input

I am trying to be able to read the contents of a file that is uploaded via the input tag to a variable where I can then use an algorithm that takes the contents of a .txt file and decrypts it:

`<input type="button" value="decrypt" id="decryptbutton">`

```
function decrypt() {
    const selectedFile = document.getElementById('input').files[0];
    var fr = new FileReader();
    let ciphertext = fr.readAsText(selectedFile);
    decrypt(ciphertext, key);

}
```

however, this does not seem to work. I have searched the internet already to try and find the answer, but I still can't figure out how to put the contents of the uploaded file into a variable.

Comment: What do you mean 'contents of a file?' a text file that's uploaded? A text field that's entered?

Comment: Yes, the contents of a text file that is uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

The reason you're having issues is that the returned value is a `promise` which isn't present yet until the promise resolves. The way to get around it is to set the value in a function that you call on success of the promise `.then( res => { theFunctionToSetValue(res) });` Then you set the variable/innerHTML with the function that's called on success.

With the code I provided, you would call decipher *inside* of `setOutput()`

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const uploadBtn = document.getElementById("upload");
  const output = document.getElementById("output");
  var outputText;
  
  function setOutput(response) {
    outputText = response;
    output.innerHTML = outputText;
  };

  uploadBtn.addEventListener("change", function() {
    var fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = function() {
    uploadBtn.textContent = fr.result;
    }
    outputText = uploadBtn.files[0].text().then( res => { setOutput(res) });
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="file" id="upload">
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Keep in mind, I didn't add filetype checks or anything like that. You'd want to add those things, but the basic concept is right there. :)